# Attach to native code when debugging unit tests through ReSharper

Tags: debugging, nunit, resharper, native-code

When using ReSharper to debug NUnit tests from within Visual Studio 2008, is it possible to have the ReSharper test runner attach to the native code debugger?  By default it only attaches the Visual Studio managed debugger.

Answer (score 8):

In the settings for your test project, in the Debug tab, check the "Enable unmanaged code debugging"